# server error in codeigniter home page in local server

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

> The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script.

The above error displayed in home page, I just download Sample CI project and configure into localhost (XAMPP server) incuding SQL dump moved.

But the site is not came in localhost, I just change base url like below:

```php
$config['base_url'] = "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/myproname/";
```

`myproname` is my project folder name in localhost.

Comment: Just keep base url blank `$config['base_url'] = ''`and try to run `http://localhost/Taxitogether/`

Comment: Try this way, too. `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/Taxitogether/';`

Comment: If you have added any htaccess for removing  **index.php** than change the config variable to this `$config['index.php'] = ' '` and also make sure mod_rewrite is on in your php.ini file

Comment: no reaction is there after changes

Answer (score 0):

Try this steps

1. Download [Codeigniter 3](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter) from here
2. in `application/config/config.php` add this

   ```
   $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/Taxitogether/';
   ```

   > if your `Taxitogether` project is inside another folder (Ex: `c:/XAMPP/htdocs/kama/Taxitogether`) then baseurl should be `http://localhost/kama/Taxitogether/`
3. Check your Database connection and .htaccess files as well

> This is the basic setup of Codeigniter